# php url edit how?

Tags: php, url

link is : info.php?Submit=#img.png

so

```
<?php echo $_GET["Submit"]; ?>
```

but this wil show : #img.png
how to remove the "`#`" from the name so it shows : `img.png` ??

thanks

Comment: substr() http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Answer (score 4):

`$_GET["Submit"]` will not contain that, since `#` marks the beginning of the 'fragment', which does not get passed to the server.

If the link is `info.php?Submit=%23img.png`, then you can trim it like this:

```
<?php echo substr($_GET["Submit"], 1); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could always modify the sender code to exclude the leading `#` (or `%23` as @Cal pointed out).

Otherwise, try one of these:

```
//substring [1:len]
$yourString = substr($_GET["Submit"], 1);

//replace "#" with ""
$yourString = str_replace("%23", "", $_GET["Submit"], 1); //1 is the limit of #s to remove

//parse the URL, then get the path
$yourString = parse_url($_GET["Submit"], PHP_URL_PATH);
```

Comment: i get this error :
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in demo.php on line 6

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you are sure that the first character is either a # or the encoding of one (%23):

```
<?php echo substr(urldecode($_GET["Submit"]),1); ?>
```